# Redirect after save in partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say the requirement is to redirect to another page after successfully saving a model in an ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        // Do save;

        return RedirectToAction("whatever"); // <--- here's the problem 
    }

    // display validation errors and so
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

This would work fine unless the controller was rendered as a Child Action:

```
@{
    Layout = "my layout";

    Html.RenderAction("something else, a view for example");
    Html.RenderAction("Index action of the above controller"); // <----
}
```

In this case RedirectResult class would check and see that the context is a child action and would throw the exception: "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions".

I understand that writing to Response stream is already in progress and a redirect cannot take place here but nevertheless one has to be able to redirect to other pages after a server-side action in a controller even if that action is a child action. We use Layouts and RenderActions to reuse the shared parts of the page design.

How would you implement such a redirect in such a controller?

Edit:

The main goal is to reuse View/Controllers that do a specific job and split them to logical concepts like displaying some data or providing an edit form. My approach here is to use RenderAction to render their result into a container. Container view (main page's Index action) acts as a traditional asp.net Page, its Layout view as a Master page and edit and view controller/views are equivalent to User Controls (modules). The problem is there is no way to Redirect the Response after something has been written to it:

[image: MVC Redirect after save problem]

Comment: Normally you redirect people after they posted some data.
The posting of data should never be a child action. What is your concrete example because it seems to me you are misusing child actions at some point :)

Comment: The code sample is actually from a concrete example. A view renders some information on top of the form (so we have two render actions and a layout in the main view) and Save button should simply redirect after a successful save (instead of displaying a message and providing a link or button for the redirect)

Comment: Still not following : your index action isn't really index , it is a save action. Why would you want to display a save action?

Comment: Say I'd have an Index action to display the form and a Put action to save the post data. Now in the end of that action I need to do a "redirect". Where would you put the code for redirect?

Comment: Please see if the code in my answer below makes any sense to you. If not we might not be on the same page :)

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is not going to work when there a Layout to be rendered. The problem is not at all about the name of the action and whether it is called Save or Index. It has a double duty (render a view or redirect) and RedirectToRouteResult's check for context.IsChildAction is preventing any redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll submit a new answer in an attempt to keep things clean.
A normal mvc flow goes like this :
Http command reaches 1 controller which acts as a choirmaster(aka controller) and calls several logic containers(e.g services / commandHandlers) :

```
public ActionResult Index(){
  var data = _yourService.FetchData();
  return View(data);
}
```

This controller renders 1 view which can have multiple partials

```
@{
    Layout = "my layout";
}
<p>Some html</p>
Html.RenderPartial("A shared partial");
Html.RenderPartial("shared\yourUserControl", Model.PropertyOrSomething);
```

If the partial contains too much logic to generate you could add a RenderAction or create an htmlHelper extension.
But neither of these should be able to control the flow of your request, a save or something that can redirect should in my opinion never be called from inside a view.
I assume you want to reuse the code in your controller so badly because it is getting quite big.
My advice would be to try and clear that controller up as much as possible by delegating as much of the logic upwards as you can.
Just by looking at your controller method for 5 seconds you should get an idea of what this action will do, if that's not the case : refactor it ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you have a parent controller which accepts a saveAction and while rendering the view you call another(?) saveAction as a child.
This flow feels unnatural to me.
 The parent action and only the parent action should handle the save command.
 You can render as many child actions as you want as long as they are only used to render some html(as this is what the view does). 
 Don't let them handle redirection or saving, that way of working is everything but transparant for colleges or future you.
The controller **controls** the flow, not the view.
Edit:
A normal setup would be having 2 actions, eg: Index and Put.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
  //fill model with dropdown data etc
  return View();
} 

public ActionResult Put(viewModel data){
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        // Do save;
        return RedirectToAction("whatever"); // <--- here's the problem 
    }

    // display validation errors and so
    return View("Index",viewModel);
}
```

Edit2:
If you return View("Index",viewModel) you will generate your index view with it's layout and the validation messages will be located in the modelstate.
Your view however should only have 1 childaction(or more if there are multiple, as long as it's not the save action).
Your Index view could look like this :

```
@{
    Layout = "my layout";
}
Html.RenderAction("something else, a view for example");
@Html.BeginForm("Put","YourController"){
  //all your input controls which will also show the validation errors
}
```

Edit 3:
If you want to reuse html code you should use @Html.Partial or Html helper extension methods. Note that if you pass no model the parents model is passed but you can pass a submodel to match the type safety of the partial.

It would look something like this :

```
@{
    Layout = "my layout";
}
Html.RenderAction("something else, a view for example");
Html.RenderPartial("shared\yourUserControl", Model.PropertyOrSomething);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is you will lose LAYOUT if you render the view as a result of a validation error. Please see the main view (the one with two Html.RenderActions and a Layout)

Comment: I edited my answer to try and make it more clear. I have the feeling i'm still missing a crucial piece of insight into your problem so please elaborate on the problem with the layout if you show your view like this.

Comment: This new approach has this downside that I need to put the source of every partial view in that shared view (the one with layout). I'd like to keep the edit forms reusable. Somehow like User Controls in ASP.NET Forms where you could put them in any page. As an analogy Layout view is master page, main view is the page and edit view and its controller can be user control.

Comment: Edit number 3 for using partials. This will allow you to reuse your views like usercontrols. The codebehind of the controller should be duplicated accross other controllers but this should only be a minimum number of controlling the request code(like loadAnEntity, Then Save it, return or show error). Hope it makes any sense to you!

Comment: I'm afraid that "code duplication" was the first thing I wanted to avoid by rendering reusable actions. Please see the explanation and picture in my edit.

Comment: Your controllers should be as skinny as possible and call services to avoid duplication of code. You're views can be fully reused, reusing your controllers is imho not in the mindset of mvc. So if your only beef with this approach is that you cannot reuse your controllers then i'm satisfied as you should not :).

Comment: Fair enough. I cannot even see any way in HTTP protocol to do this redirect after content nicely. If you'll be kind enough to elaborate your last comment in an answer I'll mark it as accepted as it is a far better explanation than other ugly workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX in your view to do this, and instead of returning a RedirectToAction in your controller, return a JSON object:

View:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '<%: Html.ResolveUrl("~/ControllerFolder/ControllerName/") %>',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#Div").html(result);
                if (result.redirectUrl != null) 
                {
                    window.location = result.redirectUrl;
                }
            }   

        });
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        // Do save;

        return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("NewAction", "NewController", RouteValues)}); 
    }

    // display validation errors and so
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm afraid ajax is not an option here. What if Javascript was disabled on the client (e.x. for accessibility reasons)?

Comment: Are the odds of the user having Javascript disabled high?

Comment: "W3C Recommendation 5-May-1999" - The odds were high in 1999, but not in 2013.

Comment: Correct, But 1) There are still clients which insist on graceful fallback in case javascript is disabled for accessibility reasons 
2) if http protocol provides a mechanism for redirect it is preferred to use that instead of inventing a new protocol for redirect.

Comment: Fair enough :) apologies that I couldn't help you out.

Comment: No worries. If javascript was an option it could have been a good solution. Thank you.