# MVC change a route after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, partial-views

I have an action that is returning data like this,

```
return _aPartialPopupView(model)
```

And after code streaming, site route changing to

```
../User/_aPartialPopupView
```

but I want to update this route to

```
../User/
```

after the action call, because it should redirect to the **index action**

I think this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/19090444/914284 answering my question but there should be more clear way to hang up

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking.   It sounds like you want to use `return RedirectToAction("User")` as you mention "after the actin call", but the mention of routes makes this unlikely (and probably a misunderstanding of routes).   Have you changed your `RouteConfig`?

Comment: i dont want to redirect i just  using this return View("_EditUser", usrObj); and this codes opens a popup but main route change the arteffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets get a route like that.

```
routes.MapRoute("old", "foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
```

And a method using like that

```
var new = routes.MapRoute("new", "bar/{controller}/{id}/{action}");
var old = routes.MapRoute("new", "foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
routes.Redirect(old).To(new);
```

MapRoute method to create the route. Or, we could have done this:

```
var new = routes.MapRoute("new", "bar/{controller}/{id}/{action}");
var throwAway = new RouteCollection();
var old = throwAway.MapRoute("new", "foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
routes.Redirect(old).To(new);
```

The implementation of GetNewRouteData which is the method called when matching incoming requests.

```
public override RouteData GetNewRouteData (HttpContextBase httpContext) {
    // Use the original route to match
    var routeData = SourceRoute.GetNewRouteData(httpContext);
    if (routeData == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // But swap its route handler with our own
    routeData.RouteHandler = this;
    return routeData;
}
```

**RedirectRoute** implements **IRouteHandler**, so we should look at its implementation.

```
  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
      var requestRouteValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;

      var routeValues = AdditionalRouteValues.Merge(requestRouteValues);

      var vpd = TargetRoute.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, routeValues);
      string targetUrl = null;
      if (vpd != null) {
        targetUrl = "~/" + vpd.VirtualPath;
        return new RedirectHttpHandler(targetUrl, Permanent, isReusable: false);
      }
      return new DelegateHttpHandler(    httpContext => httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404, false);
    }
```